# AngularJS: how to properly host ALL CRUD operations within the same service

Tags: angularjs

Being very new to AngularJS, I find myself in need of being able to host ALL of the usual CRUD operations within the same service - in my case, a service called "requestsRepository":

```
frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository', function ($http) {

    var postServiceRequest = function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests',
            method: "POST",
            data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
            console.log("postServiceRequest Status: " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.status = status;
            console.log("postServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status + "  ServiceRequest:  " + ServiceRequest);
        });
    };

    var getServiceRequests = function () {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests',
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.requests = data;
            console.log("getServiceRequests Status: " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.status = status;
            console.log("getServiceRequests FAILURE: " + status + "  ServiceRequest:  " + ServiceRequest);
        });
    };

    return { postServiceRequest: postServiceRequest, getServiceRequests: getServiceRequests };
});
```

So far, I'm having difficulty hosting postServiceRequest and getServiceRequests together.

Here is my controller, which makes a call to requestsRepository.getServiceRequests:

```
angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('ViewExistingRequestsCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope, requestsRepository) {
      $scope.requests = requestsRepository.getServiceRequests;
  }]);
```

When this call is made, I get:  Cannot read property 'getServiceRequests' of undefined
    at new  (http://myhost.mydomain.com:9221/controllers/ViewExistingRequestsCtrl.js:3:43)

My guess is, that I did not properly expose both of my functions within my service - I just do not know how to do that properly, so every function within the same service can be reached from any controller within the same app.

Comment: FYI: On line 3 of your 2nd code block, it is not a call to getServiceRequests, its just copying the reference to that function. The `()` are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like requestsRepository is undefined.

Try modifying your controller definition to look like this:

```
   angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('ViewExistingRequestsCtrl', ['$scope', 'requestsRepository',
  function ($scope, requestsRepository) {
      $scope.requests = requestsRepository.getServiceRequests;
  }]);
```

Note the addition of 'requestsRespository' in the array.

You have explicitly specified the names of the dependencies you wish to resolve when creating the controller by creating an array with '$scope' in it. This array doesn't contain the name of the service that should be injected for the requestsRespository variable. By adding 'requestsRepository' to the array, angularjs will know which service to inject.

You do not have to provide '$scope' and 'requestsRespository' in an array. Angularjs should be able to work out the names of the dependencies to resolve automatically because the names of the parameters in your controller function definition match the names of the services that are being injected. With this in mind, the following snippet should also work:

```
angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('ViewExistingRequestsCtrl', 
  function ($scope, requestsRepository) {
      $scope.requests = requestsRepository.getServiceRequests;
  });
```